# route vlan traffic to isp on Dell OS9

Tags: switch, vlan, isp, dell

I just got a layer 2/3 switch from Dell, S3048-ON with OS9 version 9.13(0.0)

I'm trying to route `vlan 20`'s clients to my ISP to reach the internet  in `vlan 10`

This is my exact configuration:

- Port `Gi 1/1` is `vlan 10` with IP from ISP `10.1.1.2` and gateway `10.1.1.1`
- Ports `Gi 1/2-2/48` are `vlan 20` with subnet `192.168.0.x/24`

What's the correct way to route my clients to the ISP? I tried various settings but I couldn't get the clients to access the internet after all

Comment: We need to see all of your configuration.  There are too many things to go wrong --we'd just end up guessing.

Comment: This is a top-of-rack switch, and I don't find any reference to it being able to NAT, which you probably need to connect to an ISP.

Comment: @RonMaupin This Dell whitepaper mentions you can through PBR although it's an old version of the software so I wasn't able to reproduce the similar configuration http://en.community.dell.com/cfs-file/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/13-4491-00-00-20-43-82-45/Policy-Based-Routing-for-Dell-Networks-1.1.pdf?forcedownload=true

Comment: PBR is not NAT. You need to translate (NAT) your private addressing to public addressing to be able to communicate on the public Internet. PBR doesn't do that.

Comment: @RonMaupin In that case I may have misunderstood the purpose of that document

Comment: @Tek, PBR is designed to make routing rules based on a specific policy. For example, you can make a policy to force some kind of traffic through a firewall...

Comment: @Tek Why do you want to use VLAN, VLAN without a correct router or firewall is generally useless and a cause of misunderstanging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a top-of-rack switch, and it doesn't have NAT. You need NAT to translate from your private addressing to the public addressing used on the public Internet.

PBR is routing based on your policies, but it doesn't do anything with your addressing. Routing is based on the destination address on the packet, but you need to change the source address of outgoing packets, regardless of how they are routed, and create a table so that replies can have the return destination changed to the originating address.

Comment: Thanks, I'll spin up a Linux VM with iptables in that case. When I got this gifted to me I suppose I just assumed all layer 3 devices support NAT

Comment: Actually, most layer-3 switches do not have NAT. Cisco claims that it requires a hardware assist to perform properly, and only the routers have that (except the 65xx switches).